# Neural Network Training Using Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, particle-swarm, differential-evolution

I want to train a feed forward neural network using Particle Swarm Optimization and Differential Evolution algorithms on Matlab, for prediction of breast cancer .

I am new to Matlab so I search and found George Ever's toolbox but I don't know how to work with it after adding the toolbox to the Matlab path. Can anybody show me the steps to train a neural network 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular reason to use the mentioned approaches for the training of the network?

Neural networks are traditionally trained using a gradient based optimizer called error back-propagation, and gradient-free methods like the ones you mentioned should most likely be slow in comparison.

Maybe you should check out some specific neural network toolboxes for MATLAB, such as the [**deep-learning-toolbox**](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38310-http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38310-deep-learning-toolbox).

In general it is most likely preferable though to use one of the popular and efficient implementations (Theano, Torch, Tensorflow, Caffe) when considering networks with many layers.

Comment: yes I want to use the network for prediction of breast cancer

Comment: You already told us in your question. But how does that answer Peter's question?

Comment: I just updated the question because i forgot to add the reason, anyway from what I understand from many papers comparing PSO and back-propagation, they end with that PSO is better. Also, my goal is to do a comparison about the performance of the 2 method

Comment: Well... these are all heuristics or metaheuristics working on a possibly non-convex problem (so we only get a local minimum). Sometimes PSO might beat backpropagation, but the classic NN-learning approaches based on backpropagation will beat PSO 99.9% of times for most use-cases. There is a reason, all modern NNs are learned with gradient- or hessian-based methods. It might be exaggerated, but *no one would use PSO for this task*. Just my opinion.

Comment: So training the  neural networks by back propagation approach with particle swarm optimization as a weight updating function will be better for good result ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it, and I've done this with particle swarm and differential evolution.  But what you'll need to do is to extract the weights and biases from the neural network manually as a vector to pass them to the optimizer and then in your objective function, you'll need to convert the vector back to weights and biases of the architecture of your neural network.